# How does the 'shiny' R package deal with data frames?

Tags: r, web-applications, twitter, dataframe, shiny

I am building a web app that downloads tweets using the 'twitteR' R package, munging those tweets and displaying them via a 'shiny' R web app. I have no problem executing the code that downloads and processes the tweets into a data frame:

```
do.call('rbind', lapply(userTimeline('nutwition_log'), as.data.frame))
```

... you can run this in your terminal (with the twitteR library loaded) yourself and see that it downloads the tweet data and prints the resulting data frame to the screen.

But, when I use this sort of call in a 'shiny' app (server-side)... for example...

---

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive(function() {
    tweets <- userTimeline(input$subscriber)
    do.call('rbind', lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))
  })

  output$view <- reactiveTable(function() {
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })

})
```

---

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('FitnessTrack'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("subscriber", "Select Subscriber:", 
                choices = c("nutwition_log", "anotherAccount")),
    numericInput("obs", "Number of observations to view:", 10)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("view")
  )
))
```

... I get the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  cannot coerce class 'structure("status", package = "twitteR")' into a data.frame
Error in as.data.frame.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  cannot coerce class 'structure("status", package = "twitteR")' into a data.frame
Error in as.data.frame.default(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  cannot coerce class 'structure("status", package = "twitteR")' into a data.frame
```

... all I want to do is be able to change the user whose tweets are being downloaded and munged, then output the resulting data frame (... the `datasetInput()` return, loaded to `output$view`) to the `mainPanel()`. I have no idea why this is not working.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Looks like a bug. You should report at: http://groups.google.com/group/shiny-discuss for whatever reason the methods for as.data.frame aren't being copied over when you call library(twitteR). Maybe even a namespace issue. When I adjust your code to use `twitteR::as.data.frame` it pumps out new errors.

Comment: This isn't a shiny bug. You get the same error with `as.data.frame(userTimeline("nutwition_log"))`

Comment: Strange though, because that's not the code he's running. But it's treating it as though he is. He's running `lapply(userTimeline("nutwition_log"),as.data.frame)`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen good point!  Your first hunch looks to be correct. This gives the error: `lapply(userTimeline("nutwition_log"), base::as.data.frame)`

Comment: Perfect timing! I was investigating this bug this morning but couldn't find a repro case. This should help a lot. I'm sure I can get to the bottom of this now.

Comment: just a question, do you know of this function `twListToDF` from the twitteR package? it takes the twitter json and turns to dataframe, use instead of `do.call('rbind', lapply(tweets, as.data.frame))`

Answer (score 10):

I think I've got it: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/commit/0b469f09df7e2ca3bbdb2ddadc8473a8126a9431

Until this is properly tested and rolled into a new Shiny build, you can test it by using devtools to install straight from GitHub:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('shiny', 'rstudio')
```

Thanks, glad to have that one fixed!

Comment: I was sure it was just a case of me just coding something incorrectly. I feel kinda stoked I could help. Saw the new "Downloading Data" section. Thanks a bunch for figuring this out!

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but there is definitely some strangeness going on here that Joe Cheng and co. would like to know about. It works, like this:

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(twitteR)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive(function() {
    tweets <- userTimeline(input$subscriber)
    tmp <- lapply(1:length(tweets),function(x) data.frame(
      text=tweets[[x]]$text,
      created=tweets[[x]]$created,
      screename=tweets[[x]]$getScreenName()))

    do.call(rbind,tmp)
  })

  output$view <- reactiveTable(function() {
    head(datasetInput(), n = input$obs)
  })

})
```

So it's not a problem with data.frames, but rather something to do with the way that twitteR sets methods for objects of reference class `status`. Running your exact same code by referencing the fields through accessors seems to run just fine.

Feels like "yet another S4 / reference class mystery".